# New keyboard the left hand side of piano sounds too heavy

Tags: keyboard

I upgraded my keyboard from Yamaha PSR E363 to Yamaha PSR SX-600 today. The problem I'm facing with this new keyboard is that the left hand side sounds too loud / bassy, I'm unsure how to change this.

Here is me pressing D note from highest to lowest octave.

https://voca.ro/12xSVYiPunOP

Here is me playing part of Rivers Flows In you, Here I press the lowest D, it sounds really weird in real life, in the recording it's less obvious.

https://vocaroo.com/1ojb91z7ajt9

I really believe that it's not me who is pressing the left side too hard.
You don't really have to exactly tell me how to do it (would appreciate it very much tho), but if someone could tell me where to look it would be great help.

However if I shift the octave of keyboard to 1 higher, and play Rivers Flows In You it sounds fine when playing left hand of the song.

Comment: Keyboard sounds fine (clip of all Ds); you're playing the low D too loudly compared to the right-hand part in "River Flows in You".

Comment: Yeah I think Aaron has a point. If it sounds like the low notes are too loud compared to the high notes, then play them softer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a hard thing to diagnose over the internet.

My guess is that the upgraded model has larger speakers, and that you've finally got a decent amount of bass, but you're not used to it.

Listen to both on headphones, and see if you still feel there's a big difference.

Comment: It might indeed be the speakers. However if I shift the octave of keyboard to 1 higher, and play Rivers Flows In You it sounds fine when playing left hand of the song.

Comment: Well, it would, because you're no longer playing a deep note.  How about with headphones?  OR. . . if the original board has a line out and the new one a line in, how about playing the old board's sounds through the new board's speakers?

Comment: I plugged my IEMs into the keyboard now the song sounds great. I think it's indeed the speakers that have too much bass. Is this generally considered a good thing?

Comment: "Too much" bass is a subjective issue.  Like I said, you're probably used to less bass, so more bass is bothering you.  Most people like having more bass, but if it bothers you, you should look for the Master EQ setting: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1861168/Yamaha-Psr-Sx600.html?page=91